# Terminated due to Memory Error when load number of images into UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios7, uiscrollview, reusability

I am using `UIScrollView` in my app that loads number of images(more then 200 images).

I load images from disk and  just add into the `UIScrollView`.I get the Xcode 5 error message "Terminated due to memory error" and app has Terminated unexpectedly.But not every time it has happened occasionally.

I am still entirely not sure this is a memory problem.But i didn't found the code cause of the Memory Problem.

Even I have checked memory leak issue through the instrument tool there is no memory leak.

I have created custom reusable `UIView` Class with help of Custom `ACReuseQueue` for `UIScrollView` like `UITableView` due to the efficiency and time consuming of the object creation

I have implemented enqueue and dequeue concept inside the `scrollViewDidScroll`:

To add image into the `UIScrollView`: used to following code

```
-(void)imageAdd:(ALAsset *)item
{
__block ImageControl    *imageControl;
imageControl = (ImageControl*)[[ACReuseQueue defaultQueue]       dequeueReusableObjectWithIdentifier:@"ImageControl"];
    [imageControl setAlAsset:item];
    [imageControl setDuration:1.0];
    [imageControl setIsCopy:NO];

    [self.galleryView addItem:imageControl];
    [imageControl release];
}
```

below code is used to when user scroll the ScrollView

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
for (ImageControl *imageControl in self.galleryView.items)
{

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageControl.frame, self.galleryView.bounds))
    {
        imageControl = (ImageControl*)[[ACReuseQueue defaultQueue] dequeueReusableObjectWithIdentifier:@"ImageControl"];


        [self.galleryView addItem:imageControl];


    }
    else
    {
        [imageControl removeFromSuperview];
        [[ACReuseQueue defaultQueue] enqueueReusableObject:imageControl];

    }
}
}
```

Still,i didn't achieve the Reusable `UIScrollView` like `UITableView`

Comment: Your images are too large. They don't need to leak if you keep adding them and they're big. You will need to use a cell strategy or something and remove images that are no longer on screen from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load all of the images at the same time. Most aren't visible anyway.

Using a table view will likely make your life a lot easier and be the fastest way of having only the required images loaded.

If you want to use the plain scroll view, you need to implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method and use it to add and remove subviews as the user scrolls the view.